# Python argparse combine commands and command arguments

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I have two commands defined (I've left out the parser/subparser sections for brevity as I don't think they would be needed to answer the question).

```
#COMMAND ARGS: Add Arguments to the final command "sacs am run [args]"
am_run_parser.add_argument("-s", action='store_const', const='s', dest='s', help="Output statistical reporting to the console.")
am_run_parser.add_argument("-S", action='store_const', const='S', dest='S', help="Output statistical reporting to the standard archive.")
am_run_parser.add_argument("-t", action='store_const', const='t', dest='t', help="Output timing reporting to the console.")
am_run_parser.add_argument("-T", action='store_const', const='T', dest='T', help="Output timing reporting to the standard archive.")
am_run_parser.add_argument("-R", action='store_const', const='R', dest='R', help="Output reject reporting to the standard archive.")
am_run_parser.add_argument("-b", "--bulk", type=int, nargs=1, help="MySQL Bulk Insert Quantity. Currently the default is set at " + str(defaults.bulk) + ". Theoretically, changing this value can affect how quickly inserts are performed.")
am_run_parser.add_argument("-host", nargs=1, help="The MySQL server host to output to.")
am_run_parser.add_argument("-port", nargs=1, help="The MySQL server port to output to.")
am_run_parser.add_argument("-user", nargs=1, help="The MySQL server username to use.")
am_run_parser.add_argument("-pw", nargs=1, help="The MySQL server password to use.")
am_run_parser.add_argument("-db", nargs=1, help="The MySQL server database to use.")
am_run_parser.set_defaults(func=am_cli_tools.am_run)

#COMMAND ARGS: Add Arguments to the final command "sacs am get [args]"
am_get_parser.add_argument("-a", action='store_const', const='a', dest='a', help="Get source A data for sacs am processing.")
am_get_parser.add_argument("-b", action='store_const', const='b', dest='b', help="Get source B data for sacs am processing.")
am_get_parser.add_argument("-c", action='store_const', const='c', dest='c', help="Get source C data for sacs am processing.")
am_get_parser.add_argument("-r", action='store_const', const='r', dest='r', help="Get source D data for sacs am processing.")
am_get_parser.add_argument("-t", action='store_const', const='t', dest='t', help="Get source E data for sacs am processing.")
am_get_parser.add_argument("-R", action='store_const', const='t', dest='t', help="Run the sacs am processor using the arguments specified after the run_args flag. This will perform the 'sacs am run' command after all specified sources are gathered (review the help file for this command for additional information about argument options).")
am_get_parser.set_defaults(func=am_cli_tools.am_get)
```

As you can see, I am in the process of adding the -R argument to the sacs am get command. Basically, I want to be able to tell sacs am get to run the sacs am run command after get finishes, and I want to expose all the associated arguments of sacs am run. e.g. sacs am get -abcrt**R -run_args** -sStTRb -host www.google.com -port 22 -user IBUser -pw IBpass -db IBpoken(lol).

Of course these run_args are only applicable with the -R argument.

I suspect there is a better way to approach this. All options are on the table. These commands do need to send an email when run (often via a cron job); this is one of the main reasons I want to have the option of combining the commands, because if I do not I will have to send 2 emails instead of one since the commands would have to be run separately. I guess I could do something else like write/append it to a file and create another sac am sendemail command for cron to run... but this approach would keep things more orderly and concise.

Comment: What about a third command, `sacs am full`, that has all the arguments of both `get` and `run`? You could organize all the arguments in dictionaries and add them to the appropriate parsers in a loop, to avoid repetition.

Comment: I had considered adding sacs am getrun, then having the associated function just call am_get and am_run; I'd also add a -e argument to the original 2 commands to optionally send an email, in case user still wanted to when running those alone. The only real problem I see with the approach is that I currently have some argument overlap and would need to change some letters for the new command, and that could confuse the user and, if they use what they are used to instead of what the help file says, it could cause some real problems... the variable names are ideal is as.

Comment: If the argument overlap can cause real problems it's easy to avoid them by renaming both versions of the overlapping ones (say, with a prefix `--get-x`). They would get an error for using the wrong argument and no risk of running with the wrong parameters. Of course, that doesn't address the problem with user experience, although they will always be using a new interface.